# create table with DISTRIBUTE BY HASH clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table with below syntax but encountered a error

```
Create Table    RRSMTB.T_Whl_Credit_Inst
(Data_Date Date NOT NULL,
MSTR_FCL_ID Varchar(36) NOT NULL,
Accounting_System_Id Varchar(10) 

DISTRIBUTE BY HASH([MSTR_FCL_ID]),
    PARTITION BY RANGE("DATA_DATE")
    (PART "PART0" STARTING('2014-01-01') IN "RRSS001_LP0",
    PART "PART1" STARTING('2015-01-01') IN "RRSS001_LP0",
    PART "PART2" STARTING('2016-01-01') IN "RRSS001_LP0",
    PART "PART3" STARTING('2017-01-01') IN "RRSS001_LP0",
    PART "PART4" STARTING('2018-01-01') IN "RRSS001_LP0",
    PART "PART5" STARTING('2019-01-01') ENDING('2019-12-31') IN "RRSS001_LP0"); 

error : incorrect syntax near DISTRIBUTE
```

Please help

Comment: Is this question tagged correctly? I don't recognize `DISTRIBUTE BY HASH` as [tag:sql-server] code. Where I can see it used in other database products, it seems to be used after closing the table definition `)`, whereas here it seems to be being applied to the `Accounting_System_Id` column.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got this create table definition from another my team lead who ask me to create this table in DB which is a sql server that is why I tagged it here and got the above error, also I am not a DB resource so not familiar with complex SQL statements .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I removed the distribute by hash clause and just keep PARTITION BY RANGE in create table but it gives me incorrect syntax error for partition now :(

Comment: @mradul Did you consider asking your team leader for help?  What you posted appears to be oracle syntax. You will need significant skills to accomplish this in sql server - so perhaps now is a good time to ask your team leader for help.

Comment: @SMor - I have already raised my issue with the team lead. but just for knowledge I was browsing through that how to create partitioned table in sql server and find docs which are creating some functions to accomplish the task !
Also oracle has PARTITION BY clause but not the DISTRIBUTE BY so it is intriguing me.